# Struggling to have my navbar properly display on desktop viewports

Tags: html, css, navigation

So while my nav displays perfectly in the mobile and tablet viewports, it's been a struggle with the desktop viewport. I just can't seem to get things to display correctly, I don't know what the problem could be, I've managed to get the logo and links parallel to each other, but every time there's an odd open block below the logo that I can't seem to fill. I've tried playing around with the main element's CSS but the block was still there. I also have a CSS Reset.

Example:
[image: example of my problem]

2nd Example:
[image]

CSS code:

```
body, img, div, label, figure, figcaption, fieldset, textarea, input, 
select, form, p, main, h1, h2, h3, h4, footer, header, nav, table, th, td, ul, li, a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
        
/* Desktop: Navigation Menu */
        .mobile-tablet-nav {
            display: none;
        }
    
        .desktop-nav {
            display: block;
        }
    
        /* 
        nav li:hover {
            background-color: white;
            border: 1px black solid;
            color: black;
        } */
    
        nav {
            background-color: #191779;
            width: 80%;
            float: right;
        }
    
        nav li a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
        }
    
        header {
            background-color: #191779;
            float: left;
            width: 20%;
        }
    
        #logo {
            padding: 0.5em;
            max-width: 90%;
        }
    
        nav ul {
            text-align: right;
            position: relative;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            height: auto;
        }
    
        nav li {
            padding: 0.3em 0;
            list-style-type: none;
            display: inline-block;
            border: none;
        }
    
    #logo {
        max-width: 52%;
        padding: 0.5em;
    }
    
     /* Mobile: Navigation */
    .desktop-nav {
        display:none;
    }
    
    /* 
    nav li:hover {
        background-color: white;
        border: 1px black solid;
        color: black;
    } */
    
    #menu-links {
        display: none;
    }
    
    nav {
        background-color: #191779;
        position: sticky;
    }
    
    nav li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        padding: 0.1em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        left: 0;
    }
    
    #hamburger {
        color: white;
        font-size: 1.8em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0.35em;
    }
    
    header {
        background-color: #191779;
    }
    
    nav li {
        border-bottom: 1px white solid;
        padding: 0.1em;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
```

HTML code:

```
<header>
            <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.JPG" id="logo" alt="logo"></a>
        </header>
    
        <nav class="desktop-nav">
    
            <!-- Navigation menu for tablet and desktop viewports-->
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html"><p>Home</p></a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html"><p>About Us</p></a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html"><p>Contact Info</p></a></li>
                <li><a href="product.html"><p>Services</p></a></li>
                <li><a href="form.html"><p>Contact Us</p></a></li>
            </ul>
    
        </nav>
    
        <nav class="mobile-tablet-nav">
    
            <!-- Hamburger button for interacting with mobile viewport navigation menu-->
            <div id="hamburger">
                &#9776;
            </div>

            <!-- Navigation menu for the mobile viewport-->
            <div id="menu-links">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html"><p>Home</p></a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html"><p>About Us</p></a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html"><p>Contact Info</p></a></li>
                    <li><a href="product.html"><p>Services</p></a></li>
                    <li><a href="form.html"><p>Contact Us</p></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </nav>
```

So I don't know what to do anymore. Thank you in advance for the help!

Kind Regards
PrimeBeat

Answer (score 0):

Move header closing tag to after the nav tags.